# how to remove soap stain from granite countertop

Tags: granite

I was fixing my dishwasher door recently and this resulted in some liquid dishwasher soap sitting on my counter for 1-2 hours.

How can I remove this stain on my counter? I can’t tell if the seal has been eaten away or if i need a special cleaner to fix this.

[image: soap stain on granite countertop]

Answer (score 1):

Automatic dishwasher soap will strip paint.

If hot water doesn't move the mark then the surface finish is damaged.